# Google plus not able to share?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-plus

Currently my web site is in staging i.e., working as IP address http://example.com. I have added google share button to share web pages in g+. When I try to share a link like this http://example.com/index/ It shows error like "There was a problem saving your post. Please try again." Can I share IP address in g+.

Please help. --

Answer (score 0):

Add a real domain to url option... That solve my problem!!!