# How to solve the error "your post was not shared, please try again" (Google+)

Tags: google-plus

I have recently seen an error with Google+, which is already reported on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808564/google-plus-not-able-to-share), although I do not find my answer there.
The error I see is that some urls (more precisely, 3 urls) of one of my sites simply can't be shared, and I couldn't figure out the problem. An attempt to ask the Google+ Help community was in vain, because we couldn't figure out what's happening.

Whenever I try to share one of those 3 urls, the Google+ error I read is as follows:

> Your post was not shared, please try again

The url I am trying to share (e.g., http://mina-grey.com/download/aa2e014df98b/) is not likely to have been reported for spam. I have read somewhere (on Google Blogger forum) that the problem may be related to encouraging illegal downloads, and it is not my case.

The url can be fetched correctly by Googlebot, and could be shared fine until I noticed the problem. Other urls that are very similar to the three I can't share can be shared fine.

I thought I could have a problem with the robots.txt file, or even the htaccess, but it isn't the case.

I thought I had problems with the validation of HTML, but a) Google doesn't seem to count errors and b) a validation of the page I can't share says there are 16 errors, mostly related to social network share buttons that can't be inside a `<div>` element.

Someone on the Help Community suggest that the page in question, in the Webmasters tool, should have tons of errors, but the tool says nothing about those specific pages.

I have *schema.org* markup for rich snippets, and those validate fine.

The page loads a Paypal purchase button, but many pages that can be shared have the same programming (see, e.g. http://mina-grey.com/interviews/1/ for the paypal button, and another url with the same exact programming but not the paypal button http://mina-grey.com/download/c060135e5e03/ . Both can be shared correctly).

Does anyone have a clue on what's going on and what can I do to fix this? I haven't found an answer and have studied this problem for days.

**Update:** a newly created URL of the kind that can't be shared has the same problem even **a few seconds** after the new item (with relative new URL) was added. This makes me think that Google can't crawl the page, or part of it. 
Because the only difference between the URLs that have issues and the ones that work properly is the loading of a  very small file into a  with jQuery, and the same process happens somewhere else, in a set of pages that have no problems, I have decided to reset the Robot.txt file, which is the only one that can give problems (or so I think), and is now as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/

Sitemap: mysite/path-to/sitemap.xml
```

If the problem persists tomorrow too, I'll just forget about Google+, I am afraid.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the URLs.

Comment: edited the question with sample urls.

Comment: I have added an update, which should hopefully be relevant. I am about to give up trying to solve this issue (lol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't ask me me why, but the reason of this problem appears to be `schema.org` structured data. After I removed of the rich snippets, I could share the the URLs that were previously blocked easily and normally. The fact that not all URLs were giving problems suggests me that the precise set of URLs with the Paypal button had some sort of non-better specified schema.org bug. 
For now I have decided to go without rich snippets. I hope the reply helps someone with the same issue.

Comment: Did you have any non-ASCII characters in the schema data?